# IR protocol for Duplo RC Dozer (2949)

Tags: electronics, remote-control

Does anyone know where to find the IR protocol for Duplo RC Dozer (2949)? I have the RC Dozer and no remote and wanted to use a universal remote to control it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have had some success through trial and error and found that a Spybotics remote will do the trick of controlling the RC dozer.